# Firebase Crash Reporting vs. Crashlytics / Fabric

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crash-reports, crashlytics

I've been using Crashlytics for a few years (now Fabric of course), and am intrigued by the recent updates to Google Firebase.

Has anyone had a chance to use both, and if so... what are your impressions?  Did you like one over the other... and why?

Thanks for any info, tips, or general observations in advance.

Have a great weekend.
:-)

Comment: In case anyone is curious -- or obviously hasn't already figured it out for themselves -- Firebase is not *yet compatible with tvOS.  Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My advice right now is to depend on Crashlytics for crash reporting until Firebase can further revise features. I've implemented both in some apps, and there are some advantages to Crashlytics. They send email notifications when crashes occur, including for priority changes, and crashes appear very quickly in the interface, within 5 minutes typically.

As it currently stands, Firebase doesn't have crash notifications, and it can take 20-40 minutes for a crash report to appear in the dashboard. A benefit of using Firebase's reporting is that their analytics will create an audience group of crash experiencing users, allowing you to identify and provide a different experience for those users (push notification, welcome screen, coupon code, etc)

**Both:**

> Ability to report logs for crashes to investigate interaction and
> function

**Crashlytics:**

> ~5 minute reporting time
>
> Email notifications

**Firebase:**

> 20-40 minute reporting time
>
> Richer user data
>
> Can redact some logged info: "Logged in Chris" could become "Logged in [REDACTED_US_MALE_NAME]"

Comment: Thanks! Firebase will clearly continue to grow its features over the years, just as crashlytics has. Exactly what I was looking for/curios about. Thanks, and have a great holiday weekend. 

Comment: Hate the fact that Firebase required internet permission. They could make a killer feature not requesting it and use play services for all the stuff instead

Comment: fabric was bought by google, firebase and fabric will merge